# How to represent functions with multiple arguments in Hindley-Milner?

Tags: javascript, types, functional-programming, hindley-milner

I'm reading a functional programming tutorial called [Professor Frisby's Mostly Adequate Guide to Functional Programming](https://drboolean.gitbooks.io/mostly-adequate-guide-old/content/ch7.html), the author gives an introduction to `Hindley-Milner` and several examples about it, one of them being:

```js
//  reduce :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
var reduce = curry(function(f, x, xs) {
  return xs.reduce(f, x);
});
```

The first argument of `reduce` is a function, whose type signature is `b -> a -> b`, and that's the exact part that I don't understand. The above code is written in js, which means `f` should take two arguments and return one, like this:

```js
function f(b, a) {
  return b + a;
}
```

Thus the type signature of `f` should be `(b, a) -> b` instead of `b -> a -> b`, right? `f` shouldn't be a first order function(implied by `b -> a -> b`), at least not in js.

So my question is, is this an error of the tutorial? If so, what's the correct way to represent `(b, a) -> b` in Hindley-Milner?

Comment: A tuple is exactly the right way to represent multiple arguments. Yes, this looks like a mistake/lapse in the tutorial - in functional programming, functions are usually curried, in javascript they aren't.

Comment: the tutorial is using lodash curry, so I believe the curried notation is referring to the "curriable" output of curry, ie, if `f(b, a) = b + a`, then `curry(f)(b)(a) = b + a`

Comment: @chiliNUT But `f` is not (should not be) curried, only `reduce` is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `xs` is annotated as `[a]`, we can expect it to be a regular javascript array.

Therefore, the `.reduce` call *inside* the `reduce` function can be assumed to be [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

This array method does not take a curried reducer function. So I would say: yes, the type annotation is wrong.

To fix it, either

1. Change the type annotation to `//  reduce :: ((b, a) -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b`, like you suggested, or
2. Change the implementation to handle passing a curried function to `Array.prototype.reduce`:

```
//  reduce :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
var reduce = curry(function(f, x, xs) {
  return xs.reduce((b, a) => f(b)(a), x);
//                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I went through this tutorial myself and I think generally functions are assumed to be curried so `f` being `b -> a -> b` is perhaps counter-intuitive but not necessarily wrong AFAIK. (Take everything I say with a pinch of salt; I'm not an expert ;)

However the parentheses around `f` itself in the `reduce` signature gives an important clue to the reader (at least to the JavaScript reader) that `f` is a function:

```
reduce :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^    ^^^    ^
          1                2    3      4

1: f
2: reduction initial value
3: list to reduce
4: reduction result
```

Since `f` *can* be curried there is no guarantee that you'll receive all its arguments in one go. Of course in this particular case (a reducing function) most people would expect that `f` will be applied to both arguments (an accumulated value and a value) at the same time.

The function signature is merely a "declaration of intent" (at least in JavaScript):

- `f` takes two arguments.
- First argument must be a `b` type.
- Second argument must be a `a` type (which *can* be the same as `b` btw).
- The return value type is a `b` type.

What the function is supposed to do is not defined.

If `b` is a number then this definition of `f` is fine AFAIK: (although that'd be a very useless reducing function)

```js
const f = b => a => 42
```